# Make custom code to reduce number of repetitive lines

Tags: java

I have to get 'tags' from the database and store them in an array so I could check if my document contains them. Due to the number of tag categories (customers, system_dependencies, keywords) I have multiple arrays to compare my document with. Is there an easy way to simplify and make my code look nicer?

This is my approach but it looks terrible with all the repetitive for loops.

```
    ArrayList<String> KEYWORDS2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> CUSTOMERS = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> SYSTEM_DEPS = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> MODULES = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> DRIVE_DEFS = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> PROCESS_IDS = new ArrayList<String>();

    while (resultSet2.next()) {
        CUSTOMERS.add(resultSet2.getString(1));
    }

    sql = "SELECT da_tag_name FROM da_tags WHERE da_tag_type_id = 6";
    stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    resultSet2 = stmt.executeQuery();

while (resultSet2.next()) {
        SYSTEM_DEPS.add(resultSet2.getString(1));
    }

    while (resultSet.next()) {
        String da_document_id = resultSet.getString(1);
        String file_name = resultSet.getString(2);

        try {
            if(file_name.endsWith(".docx") || file_name.endsWith(".docm")) {
                System.out.println(file_name);

                XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(resultSet.getBinaryStream(3));
                XWPFWordExtractor wordExtractor = new XWPFWordExtractor(document);

                //Return what's inside the document
                System.out.println("Keywords found in the document:");
                for (String keyword : KEYWORDS) {
                    if (wordExtractor.getText().contains(keyword)) {
                        System.out.println(keyword);
                    }
                }

                System.out.println("\nCustomers found in the document:");
                for (String customer : CUSTOMERS) {
                    if (wordExtractor.getText().contains(customer)) {
                        System.out.println(customer);
                    }
                }

                System.out.println("\nSystem dependencies found in the document:");
                for (String systemDeps : SYSTEM_DEPS) {
                    if (wordExtractor.getText().contains(systemDeps)) {
                        System.out.println(systemDeps);
                    }
                }

                System.out.println("Log number: " + findLogNumber(wordExtractor));

                System.out.println("------------------------------------------");
                wordExtractor.close();

            }
```

As you can see there are 3 more to come and this doesn't look good already. Maybe there's a way to compare all of them at the same time.

I have made another attempt at this creating this method:

```
public void genericForEachLoop(ArrayList<String> al, POITextExtractor te) {
    for (String item : al) {
        if (te.getText().contains(item)) {
            System.out.println(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Then calling it like so: `genericForEachLoop(MODULES, wordExtractor);`

Any better solutions?

Comment: I guess you make a query for each of those lists you declare at the top, not just `SYSTEM_DEPS`?

Comment: Correct. I need to query multiple times so decided to include my code from that point as it's already quite long and repetitive.

Answer (score 0):

I've got two ideas to shorten this: first of all you can write a general for-loop in a separate method that has an `ArrayList` as a parameter. Then you pass it each of your `ArrayLists` successively, which would mean that at least you do not have to repeat the for-loops. Secondly, you can create an `ArrayList` of type `ArrayList` and store your `ArrayLists` inside it. Then you can iterate over the whole thing. Only apparent disadvantage of both ideas (or a combination of them) would be, that you need to name the variable for your query string alike for the search of each `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is use a `Map` and an `enum` like this:

```
enum TagType {
    KEYWORDS2(2), // or whatever its da_tag_type_id is
    CUSTOMERS(4),
    SYSTEM_DEPS(6),
    MODULES(8),
    DRIVE_DEFS(10),
    PROCESS_IDS(12);

    public final daTagTypeId; // this will be used in queries

    TagType(int daTagTypeId) {
        this.daTagTypeId = daTagTypeId;
    }
}

Map<TagType, List<String>> tags = new HashMap<>();
XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(resultSet.getBinaryStream(3));
XWPFWordExtractor wordExtractor = new XWPFWordExtractor(document);

for(TagType tagType : TagType.values()) {
    tags.put(tagType, new ArrayList<>()); // initialize
    String sql = String.format("SELECT da_tag_name FROM da_tags WHERE da_tag_type_id = %d", tagType.daTagTypeId); // build query
    stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    resultSet2 = stmt.executeQuery();
    while(resultSet2.next()) { // fill from DB
        tags.get(tagType).add(.add(resultSet2.getString(1)));
    }
    System.out.println(String.format("%s found in the document:", tags.get(tagType).name());
    for (String tag : tags.get(tagType)) { // search in text
        if (wordExtractor.getText().contains(tag)) {
            System.out.println(keyword);
        }
    }
}
```

But at this point I'm not sure you need those lists at all:

```
enum TagType {
    KEYWORDS2(2), // or whatever its da_tag_type_id is
    CUSTOMERS(4),
    SYSTEM_DEPS(6),
    MODULES(8),
    DRIVE_DEFS(10),
    PROCESS_IDS(12);

    public final daTagTypeId; // this will be used in queries

    TagType(int daTagTypeId) {
        this.daTagTypeId = daTagTypeId;
    }
}

XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(resultSet.getBinaryStream(3));
XWPFWordExtractor wordExtractor = new XWPFWordExtractor(document);

for(TagType tagType : TagType.values()) {
    String sql = String.format("SELECT da_tag_name FROM da_tags WHERE da_tag_type_id = %d", tagType.daTagTypeId); // build query
    stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    resultSet2 = stmt.executeQuery();
    System.out.println(String.format("%s found in the document:", tags.get(tagType).name());
    while(result2.next()) {
        String tag = resultSet2.getString(1);
        if (wordExtractor.getText().contains(tag)) {
            System.out.println(keyword);
        }
    }
}
```

This given I don't know where those `resultSet` is declared and initialised, nor where that `resultSet2` is initialised.

Basically you just fetch tags for each type from DB and then directly search them in the text without storing them at first and then re-iterating the stored ones... I mean that's what the DB is there for.